# How to Set pivot point when using scroll wheel?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I would very much like to have the same navigation in the Forge viewer as in Navisworks, where the pivot point is set at the cursor when I use the scroll wheel on the mouse.

I have tried to get the hit point in a mousewheel event listener and then use this point in the following function: `_viewer.utilities.setPivotPoint(hitPoint,true,true`);

This kind of works, but the navigation gets a bit shaky. Is there a better approach?

Cheers,
Frode

Comment: When you said shaky what exactly did you observe (can screen capture and share to http://screencast.com)? Can you post relevant code (listener and how hitpoint is captured) as well? Try interact directly with `viewer.navigation` (which is exactly what `viewer.utilities.setPivotPoint` does) with more navigation options.

Comment: Looks like the shaky navigation was my bad. I had a test model with very huge coordinates and globalOffset set to origo. Using setPivotPoint from both utilities and navigation works fine.